# Trying to set the EditText inside FragmentDialog to be multiline doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

So I'm trying to set the edit text inside dialog to multi-lined but it doesn't do so it only appears in single-line for some reason

[image]

and it just keeps going to the right instead of going down(\n).
I set the edit text to multiline and the single line to be false but nothing works

here is the XML code for the dialog:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/item_background_gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_radio_button_unchecked_24"
            app:tint="#66FFFFFF" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_missionText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@null"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="Add mission"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
            android:lines="8"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#B0FFFFFF" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_addMission"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/item_background_gray"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabCustomSize="40dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_arrow_circle_up_24"
            app:tint="@color/add_button_background_gray" />


    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I have fixed multiline issue and also posted answer. let me know if you have any other issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and fixed the issue. You only need to remove below line from your code:

```
 android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
```

I am also posting edited code below:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/item_background_gray"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:padding="8dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_radio_button_unchecked_24"
            app:tint="#66FFFFFF" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_missionText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@null"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="Add mission"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:lines="8"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:overScrollMode="always"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="#B0FFFFFF" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_addMission"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/item_background_gray"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:focusable="true"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:fabCustomSize="40dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_round_arrow_circle_up_24"
            app:tint="@color/add_button_background_gray" />


    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's so weird I thought when you use the multiline property it will work (it worked in other projects that I did)